# Redirection to a MVC action from my View using HTML5 and BeginForm

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on a project where I am using a template for the Views and i want to redirect to my Login page from my View while posting data. I am getting the values in @BeginForm (MVC). The redirection to the Registration page is happening perfectly, but not Login. 
     Can someone guide me in this?

```
The code for my View is 

@model CDCReg.Models.RegistrationModel

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>


<html lang="en" class="no-js">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <!-- <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">  -->

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="Login and Registration Form with HTML5 and CSS3" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="html5, css3, form, switch, animation, :target, pseudo-class" />
    <meta name="author" content="Codrops" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/css/demo.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/css/style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/css/animate-custom.css" />

    <title>Register</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
        <header>
            <h1>Login  Form <span></span></h1>
            <nav class="codrops-demos">
                <span><strong></strong> </span>

                <h2>CDC Portal</h2>

            </nav>
        </header>
        <section>
            <div id="container_demo">

                <a class="hiddenanchor"  id="toregister"></a>
                <a class="hiddenanchor" id="tologin"></a>

                <div id="wrapper">
                    <div id="login" class="animate form">
                        <form action="mysuperscript.php" autocomplete="on">
 @using (Html.BeginForm(new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }))
                            {
                                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                                @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

                                <fieldset>
                                    <legend>Log in Form</legend>
                                    <ol>
                                        <li>
                                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.MailId)
                                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MailId)
                                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.MailId)
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
                                            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
                                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe, new { @class = "checkbox" })
                                        </li>
                                    </ol>
                                    <p class="signin button">
                                        <input type="submit" value="Login"  />
                                    </p>
<p class="change_link">
                                        Not a member yet ?
                                        <a href="#toregister" class="to_register">Join us</a>
                                    </p>
                                </fieldset>                                
                            }
                        </form>
                    </div>

                            @using (Html.BeginForm())
                            {
                                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                                @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
                                <fieldset>
                                    <div id="register" class="animate form">
                                        <form action="mysuperscript.php" autocomplete="on">
                                            <h1> Sign up </h1>
                                            <p>
                                                <div class="editor-label">
                                                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Username)
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="editor-field">
                                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Username)
                                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Username)
                                                </div>
                                            </p>
                                            <p>
                                                <div class="editor-label">
                                                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName)
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="editor-field">
                                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName)
                                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
                                                </div>
                                            </p>
                                            <p>
                                                <div class="editor-label">
                                                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName)
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="editor-field">
                                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName)
                                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName)
                                                </div>
                                            </p>
                                            <p>
                                                <div class="editor-label">
                                                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OrganisationName)
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="editor-field">
                                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.OrganisationName)
                                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OrganisationName)
                                                </div>
                                            </p>
                                            <p>
                                                <div class="editor-label">
                                                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Role)
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="editor-field">
                                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Role)
                                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Role)
                                                </div>
                                            </p>
                                            <p>
                                                <div class="editor-label">
                                                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Location)
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="editor-field">
                                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Location)
                                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Location)
                                                </div>
                                            </p>
                                            <p>
                                                <div class="editor-label">
                                                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MailId)
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="editor-field">
                                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MailId)
                                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MailId)
                                                </div>
                                            </p>
                                            <p>
                                                <div class="editor-label">
                                                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password)
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="editor-field">
                                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password)
                                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)
                                                </div>
                                            </p>
                                            <p>
                                                <div class="editor-label">
                                                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword)
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="editor-field">
                                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword)
                                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword)
                                                </div>
                                            </p>
                                            <p>

                                            </p>
                                            <p class="signin button">
                                                <input type="submit" value="Create" />
                                            </p>

                                            <p class="change_link">
                                                Already a member ?
                                                <a href="#tologin" class="to_register"> Go and log in </a>
                                            </p>
                                        </form>
                                </fieldset>
                            }

                </div>

            </div>
    </div>
    </section>    
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am not sure about what you are asking, but in your `html` you have `4 form tags`, may I know why? That too, you have nested form tags, which will not work. Please see if that is the issue.

Comment: What do you mean by (#tologin)?

Comment: You need to use the overload of `BeginForm()` where you specify the `actionName` and `controllerName` (by default it will post to the same action name that generated the view. But why would you have a Login and Register form in the same view (Register is a once off action for a user)

Comment: For a better Registration and Login traversal when viewing pages I have used the same Model, so that I can use it in the same Viewpage. It gives a good look and feel, to be simple.

Comment: The same model? Are you serious. Validation will fail! - for example you have  a `ConfirmPassword` on one form but not the other